What show/movie is the quote "Yonder over yonder" from?
I only vaguely remember this quote, but it goes something like:

"Where over yonder?"
"Yonder over yonder."

I'm pretty sure it's two men talking, but not 100%. I have a feeling it's from Whose Line is it Anyway, but I don't think it is.
It was most likely a comedy show. I think the two men were wearing colonial American clothing, but again I could be imagining that. It was probably over a decade ago. The only search results that show up are for a tv show called Wander over Yonder, which is not what I'm looking for.
Any help is appreciated.

Any other background details? What the men looked like, what the context was, where\when you watched it etc?

Honestly, that's about all I remember. It was most likely a comedy show. I think the two men were wearing colonial American clothing, but again I could be imagining that. It was probably over a decade ago. That quote just came to my mind and I have no idea why.

You're looking for Conan O'Brien's remote bit where he joins Civil War reenactors. While trying to impersonate a Union soldier, this conversation takes place between him and another old soldier:

Conan: I come from a little farm over yonder.
Old Soldier: Where over yonder?
Conan: Yonder over yonder.

Here's the funny clip in its entirety (the relevant bit is around 3:25):




Holy moly. That's amazing! Thanks a bunch!

@lennnnn No problem :) His old-timey baseball reenactment bit is even better.

Oh man. I've seen that more times than I can count. I'm patiently waiting for his Conan in Korea episode. Should be coming out soon, right?

Hopefully, yeah. I think he shot it last month.
